# How do you make 2 buttons appear when the mouse hovers over a triangle shape?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a food pyramid where when you hover over certain segments of the pyramid, buttons will appear but I am unsure how to code it. 
I want the `.button1` and `.button2` to appear when the mouse is hovered over `.triangle` and then I plan to do more buttons that appear when you hover over each trapezoid.

The following is the code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment01.css">
</head>

<body>

    <h1 style="font-family: helvetica">
        <center>Figure 1</center>
    </h1>

    <div class="triangle">
        <div class="circle1 "></div>
        <div class="button1"><span>+</span></div>
        <div class="button2"><span>-</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="trapezoid ">
        <div class="circle2 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trapezoid1 ">
        <div class="circle3 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trapezoid2 ">
        <div class="circle4 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trapezoid3 ">
        <div class="circle5 "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trapezoid4 ">
        <div class="circle6 "></div>
    </div>

    <h2 style="font-family: helvetica">
        <center>My Food Pyramid</center>
    </h2>

    <h2 style="font-family: helvetica">
        <center id="datetime"></center>
    </h2>

    <script>
        var dt = new Date();
        document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleDateString();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.triangle {
    border-bottom: 150px solid #FF6347;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}

.trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #f58c57;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 220px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.trapezoid1 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #fff894;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 360px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.trapezoid2 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #83ccde;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 480px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.trapezoid3 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #a87d5c;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.trapezoid4 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #9effa6;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 720px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.circle1 {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle2 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 87px;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle3 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 158px;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle4 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 219px;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle5 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 279px;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle6 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 339px;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.button1 {
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: -18px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    left: -147px;
    top: -18px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.triangle:hover+.button1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once.

Comment: It is much, much better to edit your old question and add the relevant code. Having too many bad questions under your account risks it being banned from asking.

Comment: @WaisKamal i cannot find a question with the same subject in the OP's question list !?!?

Comment: @Programmer the OP has deleted their old question, so it will only be visible to users with >10K rep.

Comment: @WaisKamal ah, i couldn't know that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class like 'piece' for each element and when you hover any element of this class, you change display:none to display: inline-block from buttons. Like the example above:

```css
.triangle {
  border-bottom: 150px solid #FF6347;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
    width: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}
.trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #f58c57;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 220px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.trapezoid1 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #fff894;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 360px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.trapezoid2 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #83ccde;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 480px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.trapezoid3 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #a87d5c;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.trapezoid4 {
    border-bottom: 100px solid #9effa6;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 720px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.circle1{
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: -22px;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle2{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 87px;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle3{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 158px;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle4{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 219px;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle5{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 279px;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle6{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 339px;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: -18px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 5px;
}

.button2{
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: -147px;
  top: -18px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 5px;
}
    
.piece:hover .button1, .piece:hover .button2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment01.css">
</head>

<body>

<h1 style = "font-family: helvetica"><center>Figure 1</center></h1>

<div class="triangle piece">
 <div class="circle1 "></div>
 <div class="button1"><span>+</span></div>
 <div class="button2"><span>-</span></div>
</div>

<div class="trapezoid piece">
  <div class="circle2 "></div>
  <div class="button1"><span>+</span></div>
  <div class="button2"><span>-</span></div>
</div>
<div class="trapezoid1 piece">
  <div class="circle3 "></div>
  <div class="button1"><span>+</span></div>
  <div class="button2"><span>-</span></div>
</div>
<div class="trapezoid2 piece">
  <div class="circle4 "></div>
  <div class="button1"><span>+</span></div>
  <div class="button2"><span>-</span></div>
</div>
<div class="trapezoid3 piece">
  <div class="circle5 "></div>
  <div class="button1"><span>+</span></div>
  <div class="button2"><span>-</span></div>
</div>
<div class="trapezoid4 piece">
  <div class="circle6 "></div>
  <div class="button1"><span>+</span></div>
  <div class="button2"><span>-</span></div>
</div>

<h2 style = "font-family: helvetica"><center>My Food Pyramid</center></h2>

<h2 style = "font-family: helvetica"><center id="datetime"></center></h2>

<script>
var dt = new Date();document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleDateString();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

OBS.: Just correct the style bacause second piece button2 is going too much to the left.

Comment: Wow thank you so much I really appreciate it

Comment: Do you know in what section of the code I can add transition-duration: to make the buttons fade in?

Comment: @Danial - changes to the `display` property don't transition well — `display:none` to `display:inline-block` always just appears. You can instead use _opacity_. Set `.button1, .button2 { display: inline-block; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s; }` (instead of display:none) then `.piece:hover .button1, .piece:hover .button2 { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: Thanks Stephen appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple example using a normal rectangular div, but it should work the same adding your complex CSS:

```css
.button1, .button2 { /* make the two buttons better visible */
    background-color: red; 
}

.triangle { /* make .triangle more visible */
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* This is the important part of the CSS which makes the buttons appear when .triangle is hovered and disappear when the mouse leaves .triangle again */

.triangle > * { /* selects all direct children of .triangle */
    display: none; /* hide the selected elements */
}
    
.triangle:hover > * {
    display: initial; /* change the display property to its initial value */
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
    <div class="button1">
        <span>+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button2">
        <span>-</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! ill see if this helps